# SimpleDateFormat не правит дату по заданному шаблону

Tags: java, android, дата, simpledateformat

Пользователь выбирает дату в DatePicker, после чего она записывается в TextInputEditText в формате "число.месяц.год". После заполнения остальной необходимой информации, всё заносится в БД. Вот только SimpleDateFormat не задаёт указанный формат.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy", Locale.US);
Date date;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(tilPurchaseDate.getEditText().getText().toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Некорректная дата. Установлено текущее время", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Введённая дата - 1.9.2017

Дата из SimpleDateFormat - Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему так происходит?

**UPD**: Решено

В адаптере RV заменил

```
tvPurchaseDate.setText(String.valueOf(purchaseModel.getPurchaseDate()));
```

на

```
tvPurchaseDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US).format(purchaseModel.getPurchaseDate()));
```

Comment: попробуйте не `.M.`, а `.MM.`.

Comment: @Tsyklop пробовал. То же самое.

Answer (score 2):

Нет никакой ошибки.

> Введённая дата - 1.9.2017
>   Дата из SimpleDateFormat - Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017

Все верно: `1.9.2017` и `Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017` - это одна и та же дата.
`SimpleDateFormat` успешно распарсил входную строку `1.9.2017` и вернул объект `Date` в переменную `date`. То что вы видите в дебаггере как `Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017` это результат вывода `date.toString()` и это никак не связано с форматом входной строки - само значение даты в `date` хранится не как строка.
При работе с БД (сохранения/получении даты) вы используете класс `Date`, а формат отображения устанавливаете в компоненте.
Если компонент принимает в качестве значения `Date`, `LocalDate` и пр. значения-даты, то нужно передавать значение, считанное из БД, а формат устанавливать в компоненте. Если компонент принимает значение как строку, то сперва форматируете в нужный формат, а затем передаете в компонент, и соответственно, в обратную сторону - парсите строку в дату, а затем сохраняете в БД.

В вашем случае:

> после чего она записывается в TextInputEditText в формате "число.месяц.год". После заполнения остальной необходимой информации, всё заносится в БД

вы используете текстовое поле ввода - поэтому придется использовать 2й вариант (парсить значения из строки вручную).

Comment: Ок, каким образом мне сохранить в бд Date и отображать её именно в том формате, в котором задал её пользователь? Вся бд отображается в RecyclerView. Мне надо задавать формат даты перед наполнением RV, а не перед записью в БД?

Comment: я дополнил ответ